# How do I make my SwiftUI app open from a string?

Tags: swiftui

It's possible to use "openURL(...)" on a View so that the system opens my SwiftUI app with a URL passed in for processing. That happens when, for example, I drag a suitable object and drop it on my app icon or open app. I want to do the same thing with my object that's represented as a String (JSON in this case). What do I call to do this, i.e., is there something like "openString(...)"?

There are a number of view modifiers like "onCommand", "onPasteCommand", etc. that sort of look like they might work but I'm missing some an overview of what the right options are to make my app respond properly to events that communicate data. Also, I'm looking for the preferred way to do this for iOS 14.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-your-app-open-with-a-custom-url-scheme

Comment: Hi @xTwisteDx, thanks but that example is for URLs, not strings. Also, I am looking for the SwiftUI for iOS14 way to do it.

Comment: @Adam it seems like there must be a better way than encoding data in the URL. If I create a local tmp file on disk with the data and then send its URL via the UIActivityViewController, will it do the right thing for email, messages, etc? Will the system know to copy the contents of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me was to use ".onOpenURL" and read the data from the URL there. To export data, create a UIActivityItemProvider that writes the data to a file in the app's tmp directory and returns its URL. These two actions can be used with the UIActivityViewController to share.